# Linear Discriminant Analysis Python: ValueError: Shape of passed values is (297, 1), indices imply (297, 2)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I want to perform a **Linear Discriminant Analysis (lda)** with the help of sklearn.discriminant_analysis in **Python**.

My dataset is structured like following:

| Prompt | Round | F1 | F3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Round 1 | Float number | Float number |
| A | Round 4 | Float number | Float number |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| B | Round 2 | Float number | Float number |
| B | Round 3 | Float number | Float number |

I want to check, whether there is a difference between the two groups A and B, given in Column Prompt in terms of values for F1 and F3. Therefore, I use **following code**:

```
from sklearn.discriminant_analysis import LinearDiscriminantAnalysis as lda
import seaborn as sns

dataset = "/XXYYZZ/Analysis/data.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(dataset)

X = df[["F1", "F3"]]
y = df["Prompt"]
post_hoc = lda().fit(X=X, y=y)

X_new = pd.DataFrame(post_hoc.transform(X), columns=["F1", "F3"])

X_new["Prompt"] = df["Prompt"]
sns.scatterplot(data=X_new, x="F1", y="F3", hue=df.Prompt.tolist())
plt.show()
```

**However**, I get the error message: "**ValueError: Shape of passed values is (297, 1), indices imply (297, 2)**". This error arises during the transform-step in post_hoc.transform(X), where it transforms X only in the dimension (297, 1). I dont understand why.

When I add a third group C to the column, it works without any problems. Also, when I perform the lda on the column "Round", which has 5 different groups, it also works fine.

Does anybody see my mistake?

Best

Answer (score 0):

To me your error stems from the inherent behavior of Linear Discriminant Analysis. When you have two classes (like 'A' and 'B' in your "Prompt" column), LDA reduces the data to just one dimension. Thus, when you try to assign this 1-dimensional transformed data into a dataframe with columns ["F1", "F3"], you're encountering a shape mismatch.

Try this to adjust the columns of `X_new` to reflect the actual dimensionality of the transformed data:

```py
X_new = pd.DataFrame(post_hoc.transform(X), columns=["LD1"])
X_new["Prompt"] = df["Prompt"]
sns.scatterplot(data=X_new, x="LD1", y=np.zeros_like(X_new["LD1"]), hue=df.Prompt.tolist())
plt.show()
```